# jQuery - How to trigger a function when Ctrl + S is pressed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
   $(window).keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 115 && event.ctrlKey){
        myfunction();
    }
   });
   myfunction(){
    alert("Key pressed Ctrl+s");
   }
```

When <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> was pressed, I don't see this myfunction is trigger. Can anyone help.? I am new to *jQuery*. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 's' is char code 83.

Comment: The ASCII value of 's' is 115 and hex value is 73. We need to consider the ASCII value only @Taplar What you have mentioned is hex value of 'S'. Anyway thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function definition is wrong:

This should work

```
$(window).keypress(function(event) {
  if (event.which == 115 && event.ctrlKey){
    myfunction();
    return false;
  }
});
function myfunction(){
    alert("Key pressed Ctrl+s");
}
```

Comment: Yes. This is what i expected. Thanks :)

Comment: `return false` prevents from saving the web page right.?

Answer (score 5):

Listen for `keyup` and `keydown`. Also, the key code for 's' is 83. This reliably works:

```
$(document).bind("keyup keydown", function(e){
    if(e.ctrlKey && e.which == 83){
        myfunction();
    }
});

function myfunction(){
    alert("Key pressed Ctrl+s");
}
```

Comment: Add `function` before `myfunction()`.  Otherwise, this does correctly capture the key press, but the browser's Ctrl+S save feature still runs.

Comment: Thanks for the typo catch! OP didn't mention anything about disabling the browser's save feature, so this should answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

As Prabhas said, your function definition was wrong.

But you'll also need to use `keydown`, not `keypress`.

Plain Javascript (which could be unreliable b/c some browsers use `event.charCode` and others `event.keyCode`):

```
  window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 83 && event.ctrlKey) {
          myfunction();
        }
    });
```

jQuery (which normalises `event.which` for `charCode` and `keyCode`, see: http://api.jquery.com/event.which/):

```
$(document).bind("keydown", function(e) {
    if(e.which == 83 && event.ctrlKey){
        myfunction();
    }
});
```